# why color property not applied on element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am trying to change color of icon . I am using color property to change icon outline color. But it is not applying .I am trying like that.

```
 "& .MuiListItemIcon-root": {
    color: "red"
  },
```

whole code is

```
const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open"
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  flexShrink: 0,
  whiteSpace: "nowrap",
  boxSizing: "border-box",
  "& .MuiListItemIcon-root": {
    color: "red"
  },
  ...(open && {
    ...openedMixin(theme),
    "& .MuiDrawer-paper": openedMixin(theme)
  }),
  ...(!open && {
    ...closedMixin(theme),
    "& .MuiDrawer-paper": closedMixin(theme)
  })
}));
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-hooks-5jcjym?file=/demo.tsx:1700-2144

When I insect color css is applied but not reflecting.Don't know where I am doing wrong.

**Expected output: Icon becomes Red **
[image]

Comment: @TimLewis I want to make this icon red

Comment: default outline of icon is white #fff. I want to make it red  to become red icon

Comment: What is the content of that `<div>` you're targeting? The `color` property sets the text colour but we cannot see what text is in it

Comment: need to change color of icon

Comment: What icon? There is not enough context or detail in your question. Please [edit] it to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looking at your CodeSandbox, you've literally set `fill="white"` into the SVG `<path>` element. Why?

Comment: @user944513 I think part of the confusion is that there's a fill on the svg's path that is setting the color to white making it invisible.  Try removing it, it should make things easier to explain / debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to change the color of an svg.  You can use the fill property to do this.

Remove the fill="white" from your svg's path so that it doesn't override the styles you apply.

```
<path
  d="M1.02991 1.79382L0 2.41036V8.20892L1.02991 5.83065V1.79382ZM17.7396 
  9.99994H0.0421995L3.30317 2.30842H21L17.7396 9.99994ZM1.59746 
  8.97196H17.0571L19.4466 3.337H3.98692L1.59746 8.97196ZM17.9133 
  1.88843L16.8834 1.27189V0.12854L17.9133 0.556457V1.88843Z"
/>
```

Update your css selector to select the svg element and set the fill to red.

```
 "& .MuiListItemIcon-root svg": {
    fill: "red"
  }
```

forked code: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-browser-4qt1ch?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: not working.. share code sandbox

Comment: @user944513 here's the forked code: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-browser-4qt1ch?file=/demo.tsx it does change the svg color to red.